# How do you compare quota counts in qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

I need to use Qualtrics to elicit responses of a group of two subjects. Participants should be randomly assigned into Participant A and Participant B.
Basically, participant A would play rock-paper-scissors game against the computer. Participant B need to place a bet on player A's final outcome of the game. Survey questions would be asked to investigate the different reaction of two players.

At the END of each participants survey, player A would be informed about whether player B placed the bet or not.  ie. I need to display the previous answer of a DIFFERENT survey participant in the Qualtrics survey.

There are two way I'm thinking of doing this: randomize and assign people into two survey streams, use quota counts for survey stream A and B. Compare the number of quota. If the number of quota counts for stream B is greater than stream A, then the next participant would be assigned into survey stream A. However, I do not know how to compare quota counts.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare quota counts.  Just check the "Evenly Present Elements" box on your randomizer and Qualtrics will keep the A & B counts equal for you.